# How to hyphenate Portuguese in plain TeX?

Tags: tex-core, miktex, languages, hyphenation

I'd like to use plain TeX in Portuguese, but I don't know how to hyphenate in this language, or in any other language than English. What do I have to do?

Comment: I'm no expert in plain TeX, but maybe you will find something here (especially the "Tabelas de Hifenação"): http://gentzen.mat.uc.pt/~gutpt/LaTeXPortugues/latexportugues.html

Comment: Thank you, but that was for LaTeX. The problem is with plain TeX. I know there's a command \language<number> in plain TeX to set the language by the language number, but I suspect it will simply not work without installing somewhere the hyphenation patterns. And I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Could it be that you are using MikTeX **portable**, which, judging from its size, perhaps wouldn't include support for portuguese?

Answer (score 4):

With XeTeX it should be as simple as:

```
\uselanguage{portuguese}
\font\test="Helvetica"
\hsize=1cm
\test
Tabelas de Hifenação
\bye
```

But if for some reason the command `\uselanguage` isn't available for you, you could try `\language=18`.

Comment: I'm using MikTeX 2.9 and I tried >xetex myfile.tex with your code but it didn't work. xetex is in the system, but it didn't work.

Comment: It's the same with `pdftex`

Comment: @egreg: the same, as in "doesn't work", or the same, as in "you can input utf-8 with pdftex"? At any rate, the example runs fine for me (basictex-2010 on osx); the "Hifenação" get hyphenated "Hife-etc.".

Comment: No, you can't input utf-8 with pdftex without defining the necessary environment; but that's not what the OP was asking.

Comment: @egreg: Sorry to bug you but I'm not clear on whether it didn't work for you, or..?

Comment: Does anyone know the number of Portuguese in the code \language <number>? I know that O (English) is the default. Where do we find this information? The TeXbook doesn't have it. In fact, the TeXbook doesn't have much practical information about changing the language.

Comment: @Orbis: how does `\uselanguage` not work for you? Doesn't the example hyphenate at all, not correctly, or...?

Comment: Look:This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=tex 2011.7.3)  5 JUL 2011 11:56
**t.tex
(C:\Temp\TeX\t.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \uselanguage
                {portuguese}
?

Comment: @Orbis: weird; I get a "xetex"-format line. The `\uselanguage` comes from—if I'm reading things right—etex. Well, in my system it would seem that portuges is `\language18`, but I'm not entirely sure if it's a "static" number (meaning: that it will be the same in your system, too).

Comment: Where did you find the munber "18"? I can't find it anywhere! Is there a documentation about it? Thank you for your kindness!

Comment: @Orbis: I grep'ped (UNIX command for printing lines matching a a pattern) the texlive-tree (for me on OSX it's /usr/local/texlive/2010basic) for `\language`. I'm not sure how I'd do that on Windows.

Comment: @Orbis: You need to use `pdftex`, not `tex`.

Comment: @egreg I used etex, xetex, pdftex and they didn't recognize \uselanguage{portuguese}. \language=18 is recognized, but it do not hyphenate. Where do I put the hyph-utf8.tex? Maybe...

Comment: @Orbis: sorry, I thought that MiKTeX builds formats like TeX Live; perhaps it's not the case. `:-(` Complain or install TeX Live.

Answer (score 3):

In Plain TeX, just set a non-used language number and then input the hyphenation patterns for Portuguese — a TeX file available in every distribution, like this:

```
\language=7
\input pt8hyph.tex
\def\portugues{\language=7\relax}
```

Patterns are associated to language number, switch the number to change hyphenation rules, or create some definitions to handle this. It works with UTF-8!

You can get this file in http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/portuguese Thanks to Pedro J. de Rezende (rezende@dcc.unicamp.br) and J.Joao Dias Almeida (jj@di.uminho.pt) for baking it.

Comment: This doesn't work in a normal document; patterns can be loaded only in iniTeX, that is at format creation.

Comment: You're right, it should be used when creating a format, I forgot to mention. Example: run `pdftex -ini myformat.tex` where myformat.tex is a file with commands like `\input plain \language=7 \input pt8hyph.tex \dump` then use the format created: `pdftex -fmt myformat` on our manuscript.

Answer (score 3):

I can propose a procedure for XeTeX; there is some that can be done also for pdfTeX, but it needs some time.

Find in your TeX distribution the file called `hylang.tex` and copy it into a working directory. Modify it to be

```
%%% This is hylang.tex (version 1.0), where language definitions
%%% actually occur. The first one should always be
%%% American English, for compatibility with plain TeX.
%%%
%%% Users can modify this file in order to define the
%%% languages they need.
%%%
%%% Every language definition should be followed by a
%%% \refinelanguage command where conventions specific to 
%%% the language are set; users should at least provide 
%%% the left and right hyphenation minima using
%%% \hyphenmins{<left>}{<right>}
%%%
%%% In the third argument one puts what has to be done
%%% when activating the language; in the fourth argument
%%% what needs to be undone.

\input unicode-letters

%%% US English must always come first
\definebaselanguage{en}{US}{hyphen} %%% <--- don't modify
\refinelanguage{en}{US}{\hyphenmins{2}{3}}{}

%%% Portuguese
\definelanguage{pt}{PT}{loadhyph-pt}
\refinelanguage{pt}{PT}{\hyphenmins{2}{3}}{}

\definedialect{pt}{BR}{pt}{PT}
\refinedialect{pt}{BR}{\hyphenmins{2}{3}}{}

%%% Add other languages if needed
%%%
%%% The arguments to \definelanguage are:
%%% #1: the language code; it is an arbitrary string, use the 
%%%     ISO two-letter language code for uniformity, or `nde' for
%%%     new orthography German
%%% #2: the nation code; use the uppercase ISO two-letter code
%%% #3: the file with hyphenation patterns
%%%
%%% The arguments to \refinelanguage and \refinedialect are:
%%% #1 and #2: a pair defined through \definelanguage or \definedialect
%%% #3: commands to be executed when entering the language
%%% #4: commands to be undone when entering a new language
%%%
% \definelanguage{xx}{YY}{xxhyph}
% \refinelanguage{xx}{YY}{<something>}{<something>}
%
% \definedialect{aa}{BB}{xx}{XX}
% \refinedialect{aa}{BB}{<something>}{<something>}

% At last the fallback, a language with no patterns
\definelanguage{zz}{ZZ}{zerohyph}
% \refinelanguage{zz}{ZZ}{}{} % no need to set conventions

%%% Aliases
\addalias\US{en}{US}
\addalias\PT{pt}{PT}
\addalias\BR{pt}{BR}
\addalias\ZZ{zz}{ZZ}
\addalias\nohyphens{zz}{ZZ}

\endinput
```

Now call the initialization program

> `xetex -ini '*hyplain'`

This will create a new format file `hyplain.fmt` and you can test it by running

> `xetex '&hyplain test'`

where `test.tex` is

```
\font\standard="TeX Gyre Termes/mapping=tex-text"
\standard

\parindent=0pt

\selectlanguage{pt}{PT}

\hsize=2pt

\hskip0pt
Tabelas de Hifenação

\hskip0pt
Lisboa possui inúmeras atracções turísticas. A baixa pombalina, Belém,
Chiado ou Bairro Alto, são zonas onde afluem milhares de turistas e
visitantes anualmente. Duas agências europeias têm sede em Lisboa: o
Observatório Europeu da Droga e da Toxicodependência e a Agência
Europeia de Segurança Marítima, ambas com projectos de novas sedes à
beira rio. A Comunidade dos Países de Língua Portuguesa encontra-se
igualmente sediada em Lisboa.

\bye
```

The format file can be moved in a suitable directory, consult the manual for your distribution in order to see where and how.

Caveat: I wrote the "hyplain" system.

Comment: It's difficult to answer to "didn't work".